# How to add NSDictionary as a value in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSString *>*>*mainDict;
```

So it is a dictionary with another dictionary as its value.
Now, when I wanna populate my dictionary, I do:

```
NSData *data = [json_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

for (NSString *key in [[json objectForKey:@"countries"] allKeys]) {
    NSDictionary *innerDictionary = [json objectForKey:@"countries"][key];
    [mainDict setObject:innerDictionary forKey:key];
}
```

when I debug, I see that my `innerDictionary` is correct and has its values but somehow my mainDict is not being filled.

Could you please tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you created mainDict somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Andrea no, just added the property in interface section

Comment: If you don't create in the init or other part of your code and assign to self.mainDict it would be just a pointer that points to nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring mainDict as a @property will create an instance variable in your class, but that variable will be nil.

You'll need to initialize the mainDict somewhere before your population code gets called, perhaps in your -init, -viewDidLoad, or somewhere appropriate for your app's architecture.

mainDict initialization should look like:

```
mainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: `mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary new]` is a bit shorter and works as well.

Comment: but I love this form `mainDict = @{}.mutableCopy`

Comment: I also like the form of ```mainDict = @{}.mutableCopy```, but it's suboptimal. You're making two dictionaries in order to get one dictionary. (Of course in practice this difference won't be felt in 99.99% of cases, unless the code is inside some uber-tight loop or parallelized to the hilt.)